# Create TableView dynamically, with different Content (JavaFX)

Tags: java, dynamic, java-8, javafx-2, tableview

i'm trying to create multiple TableViews in Java with JavaFX.
I got a Controller and a FXML file. If i create multiple Tables from the 
same FXML i get the same content. Is it possible to create multiple 
TableViews with different content?

This is how it looks like now:

MainApp

```
/**
 * CreateAndShowTable
 */
public void CreateAndAddTable() {
    try {
        getNextTableData(); // Here i change the Data 
        // Load person overview.
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource(url));
        tableList.add((TableView) loader.load());

        // Sets the TableViews, only 3 in one Row

        if(colIndex % 3 == 0){
            rowIndex++;
            colIndex = 0;
        }
        tablePane.add(tableList.get(tableList.size()-1), rowIndex, colIndex);
        colIndex ++;


        // Give the controller access to the main app.
        TableViewController controller = loader.getController();
        controller.setMainApp(this);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

TableViewController:

```
 /**
 * Is called by the main application to give a reference back to itself.
 * 
 * @param mainApp
 */
public void setMainApp(MainApp mainApp) {
    this.mainApp = mainApp;
    // Add observable list data to the table
    dataTable.setItems(mainApp.getTableData());
}
```